# Can I force a Java method to return at a certain point?

Tags: java

I have a servlet that receives data, and if the data is OK, it persists it.

So far, I tried the following:

```
public class ListenerServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if(!check1())
    handleErroneousRequest(response, "Error 1");

    if(!check2())
    handleErroneousRequest(response, "Error 2");

    persist();

}

private void handleErroneousRequest(HttpServletResponse response, String errorMessage) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        log.error("Error : " + errorMessage);
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, this did not work as I expected. 
Is there a more elegant solution than a series of if else ? Can I force the method to return as I tried to do?

So far, I was panning on doing something like this:

```
boolean isOK = true;
if(!check1()) {
    isOK = false;
    error = "bla";
}

if(!check2()) {
    isOK = false;
    error = "bla";
}

if(isOK){
    doStuff()
}
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote me, at least have the decency to explain why...

Comment: What prevents you from using a `return` where needed?

Comment: That is a very good idea. Let me try.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. If you post it as answer, I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: It works, but this is a quite "gore" way to handle errors -- Exceptions are made for it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to *return* from a method in Java, you can use the `return` statement.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (!check1()) {
        handleErroneousRequest(response, "Error 1");
        return;
    }

    if (!check2()) {
        handleErroneousRequest(response, "Error 2");
        return;
    }

    persist();

}
```

There are, however, at least two even better ways to solve this particular task: **if-then-else** and **exceptions**.

Using **if-then-else** and **else-if**, you can write the whole method as follows:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (!check1()) {
        handleErroneousRequest(response, "Error 1");
    } else if (!check2()) {
        handleErroneousRequest(response, "Error 2");
    } else {
        persist();
    }
}
```

The brackets are optional for single-statement blocks, but I included them for clarity.

Another way to solve the problem is by using *Exceptions*. In this case, the `check1` or `check2` methods should throw an Exception. Any uncatched exception immediately halts method execution, which also applies to the remaining statements in a `try`-block. *Exceptions* can thus be used to control the flow of the program as well.

However, *Exceptions* should be used if the behavior is, well *exceptional*. *Validating* stuff *expects* validation to fail, so from an architectural perspective, one should return sensible validation results instead.

However, if you choose to use Exceptions, one way to use them would be as follows (assuming `check1` and 'check2' throw Exceptions):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        check1();
        check2();
        persist();
    } catch (MyAwesomeException e) {
         handleErroneousRequest(response, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You can also opt *not* to handle the Exception yourself (omit the try-catch block) and let the Exception bubble up the stack back to the calee - the container - and configure it as @mikibrv has posted in his answer to display an error message to the user. This is especially helpful if you can not recover from the exception inside the program and the only sensible thing to do is to inform the user.

There are, however, many situations in which you can gracefully recover from an exception and never need to inform the user about it.

Comment: Thanks. I knew all this, but I never thought of using returns in Servlets (who knows why)

Answer (score 1):

It would be an idea to use exceptions in your checks. You can throw some custom exceptions extending ServletException (which is the standard exception thrown in a servlet).

You can catch that exception in a handler where you can display something  custom. No need for if/else and you will have a nice separation of what is exception handling and what is your actual code.

Here is a tutorial that can help you with what you want to achieve: http://www.journaldev.com/1973/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial

Check the configuration in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
  <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
  </error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but then I have no status code for the caller. The servlet is not being called in a browser, but by another program. I cannot  set the response status code in case of an Exception, can I ?

Comment: Encapsulate the code you use to check your data in a try block. Throw an exception when the data isn't valid. Then, in a catch block, handle the exception, and set the response as needed.

Comment: But then I'll still need the return, otherwise the code will continue. Or did I miss something ?

Comment: If something within a try block produces an exception, the rest of the try block won't get executed, it will directly execute the code corresponding the catch block of the Exception thrown. Catching an exception within the try block completly avoids the rest of the code of the try block.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you meant one try catch per check.

Comment: Ok it works. Thanks. Mind posting this as an answer ?